# Can deserialize accept further parameter?

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization

Usually this is how I created objects

```
Public Shared Function createBasicSimpleOrder(ammountOfQuoteCurrencyBeingOrdered As Decimal, priceInBasecoin As Decimal, Base As String, Quote As String, exchangeObject As ExchangesClass, isSellingInsteadOfBuying As Boolean, customIdentifier As String) As BasicSimpleOrder
    Dim exchangeString = exchangeObject.ExchangeStringName
    Dim a = New BasicSimpleOrder(ammountOfQuoteCurrencyBeingOrdered, priceInBasecoin, Base, Quote, exchangeString, isSellingInsteadOfBuying, customIdentifier)
    a.initializeComplexObjects(exchangeObject)
    Return a
End Function
```

Basically one of the parameter is an object

```
exchangeObject As ExchangesClass
```

That is the only non primitive Object that is a member of `BasicSimpleOrder`
So after I set up the primitive Public Read Only properties, I called this function.

```
Public Sub initializeComplexObjects(exchangeObject As ExchangesClass)
    _exchangeObject = exchangeObject
    If exchangeObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim mark = CoinClass.MarketBaseQuoted(exchangeObject.ExchangeStringName, Base, Quote)
    If mark Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    setMarket(mark)
End Sub
```

Now say I want to deserialize

I then do

```
gridOrderOldState = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of futureStateForGrid)(settingsFromBefore)
```

Basically `futureStateForGrid` is a class that contain some derived class of `BasicSimpleOrder`

For that DeserializeObject to work I already set a constructor

```
Protected Sub New(ammountOfQuoteCurrencyBeingOrdered As Decimal, priceInBasecoin As Decimal, Base As String, Quote As String, exchangeString As String, isSellingInsteadOfBuying As Boolean, customIdentifier As String)
    _ammountOfQuoteCurrencyBeingOrdered = ammountOfQuoteCurrencyBeingOrdered
    _Base = Base
    _Quote = Quote
    _priceInBasecoin = priceInBasecoin
    _exchangeString = exchangeString
    _isSellingInsteadOfBuying = isSellingInsteadOfBuying
    _customIdentifier = customIdentifier
    'initializeType0(ammountOfQuoteCurrencyBeingOrdered, priceInBasecoin, Base, Quote, exchangeString, isSellingInsteadOfBuying, customIdentifier)
End Sub
```

The problem is if I use DeserializeObject, I cannot run initializeComplexObjects(exchangeObject As ExchangesClass)

That's because my new (constructor) function does not accept exchangeObject as ExchangeClass as parameter.

If Protected Sub New accept exchangeObject as ExchangeClass  as a parameter, newtonsoft won't know which object should be put on parameter. After all ExchangeClass is a complex object and not a primitive type. Hence, they're not really there.

So how can I set the exchangeObject as parameter so the constructor know?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  None of your classes are actually shown, so we can't test any solutions.  Options might include: 1) Using an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callback to run `initializeComplexObjects`.  2) Using a [custom creation converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/customcreationconverter.htm) to inject constructor arguments known in runtime by the caller.  But I can't really say for sure whether either would work without being able to see a complete example.

Comment: It is reproducible. 

The principle is after running deserialize I should run a code that initialize the complex variable. It seems I can't do that within the deserialize itself.

Comment: *It is reproducible.* -- I tried to reproduce your issue with the code shown, and it doesn't compile.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/TWY5XG.  Is there any chance you can [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that shows your problem?  As it is, none of your classes are full defined an your JSON is not shown.

Comment: **Maybe** your problem would be solved by marking the constructor of `futureStateForGrid` with `[JsonConstructor]` and calling `initializeComplexObjects` from with an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbackAttributes.htm) callback but it's hard to say for sure absent a [mcve].

Comment: I can give simpler sample. Ah onDeserialized maybe what I should do. However, just finish initializing after deserialize works too.